# React Native code hot load

Tags: react-native

App store prohibits downloading remote code with the sole exception of WebKit + JS:

> 3.3.2 An Application may not download or install executable code. Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if all scripts,
>   code and interpreters are packaged in the Application and not
>   downloaded. The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code
>   downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework, provided that
>   such scripts and code do not change the primary purpose of the
>   Application by providing features or functionality that are
>   inconsistent with the intended and advertised purpose of the
>   Application as submitted to the App Store.

Does this adhere to React Native? Can I host my React Native script bundle on a CDN server and fix bugs by replacing my JS implementation?

See: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app.html#add-rctrootview-to-container-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are allowed to hot load JS into your iOS app. This is one of the big advantages of React Native.

Comment: Do you have a source for your claim about the Facebook app?

Comment: Oops. I was wrong here. I found that facebook bundles their JS code with the app.

"That said, none of our existing React Native apps at FB are downloading their code in production - they all use static bundled JS as suggested in the documentation."

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/935#issuecomment-94653987