# How to download and run code using eval on React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, eval

**Context:**
We are already using a framework to develop our mobile app which is pretty similar to React Native (We write everything in JS and it runs on Android and iOS).
Our framework provides some built-in APIs to display things on the screen and do other stuff.
*Example:*

```
function homePage() {
   List.addTitle("Welcome");
   List.addButton("Next", "goToNextPage()") // List.addButton(label, onclick)
   List.show() // will display currently what is in the buffer or List
}
```

On Android, when a user logs in, they will download the latest code and run it (via `eval`). On iOS, we need to make a new build and submit to Apple everytime we need to release a new version

**Goal**
The goal is to migrate to React Native and only reimplement the basic APIs of the old platform (like `List`) so that we can keep using the code that we already wrote.

I've seen solutions like [CodePush / AppCenter](https://appcenter.ms/) but our code is not in ReactNative yet so I don't think it will work for us.
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434695/react-native-code-hot-load) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249045/react-native-dynamically-load-modules-plugins) are related but do not have concrete answers.

I've written a small [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/ryFCJG8XM) to give you an idea of how I hope it would work.

1. The `Login` component handles the login
2. The `SignIn` component evals the code and renders whatever is in that code

**Question**

1. I had to reimplement the `List` API in the same file as `SignIn.js`.
   If I try to import it, then `List` will be undefined in the eval.
   Why?
2. With this method, the downloaded code will have to be `eval`'d everytime we refresh the page or navigate to another screen. I'm worried about the performances, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks a lot for your help